# Python 3 - Issue importing module - from Parent Directory - that contains File Descriptor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am unable to do what I believe should be a simple import of a python3 module from a file's parent directory.  I can get the module import to work from a parent directory without issue *until* I introduce a file descriptor into the file that is to be imported.

Example # 1 below is a 'works fine' scenario and # 2 is the problematic scenario that I'm hoping for suggestions on.

## #1 - Works fine

#### App Directory structure:

```
├── app
│   └── app.py
├── config.py
```

#### File contents:

```
# app.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
from config import Config as conf

foo = conf.foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hello from app main')
    print(f'foo is --> {foo}')


#config.py
class Config():
    foo = 'bar'
```

#### Run it:

```
$ pwd
app/
$ python app.py
hello from app main
foo is --> bar
```

## #2 - Does not work / Fails

#### App Directory structure:

```
├── app
│   └── app.py
├── config.py
└── foo.txt <-- **Introduced new file here**
```

#### File contents:

```
# app.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
from config import Config as conf

foo = conf.foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hello from app main')
    print(f'foo is --> {foo}')

# config.py
class Config():
    with open('foo.txt', 'rt') as f:
        foo = f.readline().rstrip()   
    
# foo.txt
bar
```

#### Run it:

```
$ pwd
app/

$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from config import Config as conf
  File "../config.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Config():
  File "../config.py", line 2, in Config
    with open('foo.txt', 'rt') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong here?  And please note that foo.txt *does* in fact exist in the parent directory despite the "FileNotFoundError" error message.

```
$ cat ../foo.txt
bar
```

Thanks.

Comment: put the foo.txt in the app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are using a relative path. This:

```
open("foo.txt")
```

will lookup foo.txt in the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), whatever it is at this exact moment (which means that it can be just anything and that you should NEVER assume anything about it).

> And please note that foo.txt does in fact exist in the parent directory despite the "FileNotFoundError" error message.

Yes, it exists in the parent directory, but not in the **current** directory.

The canonical solution here is to rebuild the proper path using `os.path` functions and the `__file__` magic variable:

```
# config.py
import os

def read_foo():
    # build the full path to the current file
    here = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    # extract the directory path
    dirpath = os.path.dirname(here)
    # foo.txt is supposed to be in the same directory:
    foopath = os.path.join(dirpath, "foo.txt")
    with open(foopath) as f:
        return f.readline().rstrip()
```

Now you can safely call `config.read_foo()` from any other module, whatever the current working directory is.

As a side note: reading a file in a `class` statement block is possibly not a great idea - not that it's illegal in Python but it's really a design smell...